# How to get a numpy array from a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list

```
list_num = [4 , 5 , 6]
```

How to convert it into a numpy array with of shape ( , 3) as when using the function

```
res = np.array(list_num).shape
```

output is ( ,3 )

Comment: Can you make your question clearer please? Not sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Precisely what is the problem with the code you've tried?

Comment: Something like `arr = np.array(list_num).reshape(1, 3)` ?

Comment: res = np.array(list_num) is fine juste remove .shape

Comment: `res = np.array(list_num).shape` is assigning the shape (`(,3)`) and not the array to `res`.

Answer (score 0):

If printing the `res` variable shape, the result is `(3,)` and not `(,3)`, so I will understand you have mistyped that.

Just removing the `.shape` from `res`, as imM4TT user had cited, the variable will be like you need: `res = [4 5 6]`.

If printing the `res.shape`, you will obtain `(3,)`.

If you really want to reshape to an array with size `(,3)`, its necessary to use what executable user had cited, the reshape function:

```
res = res.reshape(1,3)
```

Comment: In python `(,3)` will give a syntax error.  In `(3,)` the ',' makes a tuple.  `(3)` is just `3`.